# Where does Joomla's getParams() function find the parameters from a directory?

Tags: php, html, joomla, web, content-management-system

I'm working on an existing website w/ **Joomla** as the CMS. A line of **PHP** code that I came across for fetching the user's payment info is:

```
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_paymentportal');
```

*com_paymentportal* is a directory, not a file or object. So where is it fetching parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `JComponentHelper::getParams('com_whatever')` simply grabs configuration parameters of a component from the database. The table `#__extensions` has a column `params` which holds the configuration object for a component.

Here are some interesting links:
http://www.webtechriser.com/tutorials/82-joomla-3-0/85-get-component-module-and-plugin-parameters-in-joomla-3
https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JComponentHelper.html#method_getParams

Answer (score 0):

You need to log into the Joomla admin side of the site you're developing.

"com" is short for "Components"; when logged in, click the "Components" tab in the top tool bar. Then traverse to the correct component such as "Payment Portal" as seen in the question.